# Awk - Conditionally print an element from a certain row, based on the condition of a different element in a different row

Tags: awk

Say I have a lot of files with a consistent number of columns and rows, and a sample one looks like this:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

I want to print column 3 of row 2, but only if column 3 of row 3 == 4 (in this case it is 9). I'm using this logic is a means to determine if the file is valid for my use-case, and extract the relevant field if it is.

My attempt, based on other answers to people asking how to isolate certain rows was this: `awk 'BEGIN{FNR=3} $3=="4"{FNR=2;print $2}'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so you are looking for something like this?

```
awk 'FNR==2{ x = $3 }FNR==3 && $3=="4"{ print x }' file.txt
```

cat file.txt

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 4
```

Output:

```
6
```

cat file.txt

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Output:

Nothing since column 3 of row 3 is 9

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR==3 && $3==4{print p} {p=$3}' *
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another which doesn't care for the order in which the records appear. In the OP the problem was to print a value (`v`) from 2nd record based on the tested value (`t`) on the 3rd record. This solution allows for the test value to appear in an earlier record than the value to be printed:

```
$ awk '
FNR==2 {          # record on which is the value to print
    v=$3
    f=1           # flag indicating the value v has been read
}
FNR==3 {          # record of which is the value to test
    t=$3
    g=1           # test value read indicator
}
f && g {          # once the value and test value are acquired and
    if(t==4)      # test the test
        print v   # output
    exit          # and exit
}' file
6
```

Record order reversed (`FNR` values changed in the code):

```
$ cat file2
1 2 3
7 8 4 # records
4 5 6 # reversed
$ awk 'FNR==3{v=$3;f=1}FNR==2{t=$3;g=1}f&&g{if(t==4)print v;exit}' file2
6
```

Flags `f` and `g` are different from `v` and `t` in case either should be empty (`""`).